# Why does referencing .self work instead of type.sharedInstance?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, ios9

I have some code like this:

```
class miniUser {

    ///The shared instance of miniUser.
    static let SI = miniUser()

    init()
    {
        self.currentUser = self.getCurrentProfile()! as String
        self.refreshUserList()
    }

...

}
```

That code works fine. However, this code using the shared instance...

```
class miniUser {

    ///The shared instance of miniUser.
    static let SI = miniUser()

    init()
    {
        miniUser.SI.currentUser = miniUser.SI.getCurrentProfile()! as String
        miniUser.SI.refreshUserList()
    }

...

}
```

That does not work. In fact, it doesn't even spit out an error during runtime, it just freezes at 0 fps (I'm using SpriteKit) when another part of the code tries to initialize it.

Ideally, both versions of the code should mean the same thing.

Could anyone explain to me why using self.function() works instead of type.sharedInstance.function() during initialization? I'm not sure about it and need an explanation to understand what is happening here.

Any help is-- err, any explanations are appreciated.

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering, I did file a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition `let SI = miniUser()` will call the `init()` of your class in order to create the shared instance. However, `init()` is trying to access the shared instance `miniUser.SI`, so this is a recursive definition. It probably shouldn't be allowed at all by the compiler — I'd suggest [filing a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com). If you need to modify instance variables during initialization, that's what `self.` is for. (In fact, you can leave out `self.` because it's implied.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!